# Add parameter in Ajax call if a conditions is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my previous code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Test/Save",
    data: {
        comments: $('#comments').val()
        <% if (SomeCondition) { %>,
            profit: parseInt(profitCombo.getSelectedValue())
        <% } %>,
        myData: JSON.stringify(someData).toString()
    }
...
```

Now, I placed this code in a separate JS file and I need to remove the ASPX call. I have a variable someConditionJsVariable, so I want to make something like this:

```
data: {
        comments: $('#comments').val()
        if (someConditionJsVariable) {,
            profit: parseInt(profitCombo.getSelectedValue())
        },
        myData: JSON.stringify(someData).toString()
    }
```

If that variable is true, add a comma and another parameter. how to make this?

Comment: Can the object passed to `data:` in the ajax call be constructed elsewhere? Can this logic be wrapped in a function?

Comment: @AnishPatel Yes, yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update code to following

```
// create object
var data = {
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
        myData: JSON.stringify(someData).toString()
    }

if (someConditionJsVariable) {,
     data.profit = parseInt(profitCombo.getSelectedValue());
}

data : data // pass object
```

Answer (score 1):

Just build your object before, using a function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Test/Save",
        data: getMyDataObject()
        //other settings
});

function getMyDataObject() {
  var myDataObject = {
   comments: $('#comments').val()
   myData: JSON.stringify(someData).toString()
  }

  if (someConditionJsVariable) {
            myDataObject.profit= parseInt(profitCombo.getSelectedValue());
  }
  return myDataObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap all of the logic into a function like so:

```
var testSave = function(someConditionJsVariable, someData, profitCombo) {

    // construct your data object
    var data = {
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
        myData: JSON.stringify(someData),
    }

    // assign the conditional property with value depending on condition
    !!someConditionJsVariable && (data.profit = parseInt(profitCombo.getSelectedValue()));

    // return the jQuery promise from ajax call
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Test/Save",
        data: data
    });
}
```

And then use the function like this:

```
testSave(someConditionJsVariable, someData, profitCombo)
    .then(function(result) {
        // do something with result
    });
```